# Naming the class of hello world program for Mac in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, class, nsview

I am programming a hello world program and I'm new to Xcode. I followed the tutorial that was in the Apple developer website

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_quick_start/010-Tutorial_Using_Xcode_to_Write_Hello_World/hello_world_tutorial.html

When I tried to make a new file with Objective-C class in Cocoa for Mac OS X, it required the Class name while in the tutorial it was only saying "Subclass of `NSView`
(# 3 in the tutorial).

I put `NSView` and then clicked [Next] and now it is asking where to put the new file but not the name of the file.  In the tutorial (# 4), there is "Save As `HelloView.m`.

What am I supposed to name the Class name?  `NSView.m` or `HelloView.m`?

(I cannot post the snapshots because I'm new to stackoverflow....)

Comment: Thank you for the answers, and I actually named it HelloView.m.  Now I have a different problem with Custom Class, which I will post soon (I can only post questions every 20 minutes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSView is the name of the superclass so you don't want to call your class that, so I would go for HelloView. Your class inherits all the functionality from its superclass, then it can add to or override this behaviour as it requires. HTH

Answer (score 0):

By following this guide, you can't use NSView for the name as it is the name of the superclass.

So try to name it HelloView.m, it is the best way to make it without any problem i think.